# luigi task based on ternary operator

Tags: python, luigi

I have a requirement where DAG looks like following

```
                   -> Task C -> Task D
                  | 
Task A -> Task B -
                  |
                   -> Task E -> Task F
```

Task B have a python ternary operator which decides what direction/leg to execute at runtime i.e. runtime flow will be either (Task C, Task D) or (Task E, Task F)

How can we define this under luigi task requires function ? Any idea or code snippet will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [dynamic dependency](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dynamic-dependencies).

I think in your example you'd have a task `G` that would depend on `B` and based on the output of `B` yield `C` and `D` or `E` and `F`

```
import luigi

class GTask(luigi.Task):
    def requires():
        return BTask()
    
    def run():
        if check_b_outout(self.input()):
            yield CTask()
            yield DTask()
        else:
            yield ETask()
            yield FTask()
```